# How can I use Nautilus in Fluxbox? It adds gnome desktop, makes fluxbox menus unusable

Tags: linux, desktop, window-manager, nautilus, fluxbox

I am running Fluxbux on Ubuntu Linux desktop machines and I noticed this happens at least on Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 13.04:

I installed Ubuntu, and afterwards Fluxbox and set it as window manager.

**When I start nautilus this results in a messed up Fluxbox**, most notably the gnome desktop background becomes my fluxbox desktop and afterwards I **cannot bring up the fluxbox menu by right clicking** on the desktop.

How can I run nautilus (and probably others applications) and teach them not to mess up my Fluxbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to nautilus rendering the desktop. You can start nautilus without the desktop with `nautilus --no-desktop` but there doesn't seems to be an option to always do it that way.

Either do something like create a shell script in `~/bin` named `nautilus` that does `exec /usr/bin/nautilus --no-desktop "$@"` or patch nautilus so that the `--no-desktop` option is always enabled.

Comment: Dan that is a great answer, I will try to avoid nautilus.

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu 16.04

Execute the following command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

This should stop Nautilus from handling right-clicks on the desktop.

<sub>(For future reference: this was  tested to work with Fluxbox and nautilus 3.14.3)</sub>